# Consistent 3 minute timeout in web.py: 503 error

Tags: python, web.py

For example, the basic web application below will give a 503 Service Unavailable error:

```
import web
import time

urls = (
    '/error', 'Error'
)

class Error:
    def POST(self):
        # sleep a long time to cause the timeout
        time.sleep(1000)
        # return
        return "All good"

app = web.application(urls, globals())
app.run()
```

This is how I make the http call (simple example, showing method):

```
import urllib, urllib2, httplib
import time
import sys

start_time = time.time()
try:
    # in practice, there's an actual dictionary passed here
    release_data = urllib.urlencode({})
    # in my case, testing with a "url" of machine on local network running the web app described above
    http_url = r"http://my_url:my_port"
    release_request = urllib2.Request(http_url, release_data)
    release_response = urllib2.urlopen(release_request, timeout=sys.maxint).read()
except (urllib2.HTTPError, urllib2.URLError, httplib.HTTPException, socket.timeout) as e:
    print time.time() - start_time
    print str(e)
```

the above code gives output below:

```
180.231
HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I've tested this many times, and the timeout always occurs within +/- 0.5 seconds of 180 seconds.

Is there any way to configure the web server so this timeout doesn't occur?

Comment: Timeout is for secury reason. Suppose I send 1 000 000 requests to your server and server runs all requests without timeout. Probably no one else will be able to reach the server. You have "Denial-of-service attack"

Comment: That's good to know, but is there any way to disable the timeout?  I'm sure that all requests to the server will be well-intentioned.  At the very least, I'd like to lengthen the timeout.

Comment: Is my only option to modify the web.py package for my own purposes?  I can do that but this seems like something with a relatively simple solution.

Comment: I run your server code on Linux Mint and I try to connect to `http://localhost:8080/error` (using your client code, my code with `requests` module or Firefox browser) and it works correctly even with `time.sleep(1000)`

Comment: Thanks furas!! It turned out that a ftp server (pyftpdlib) running at the same time was changing my default socket timeout length.  Web.py was continuing as if nothing was wrong.  Without your help I would have kept looking at web.py and gotten nowhere :)